# Paginar un formulario Django !NO LOS RESULTADOS!

Tags: django, django-forms, paginación

Buen día, quisiera saber si es posible paginar un formulario que estoy haciendo en django, el formulario es bastante extenso, con 50 preguntas aproximadamente y quisiera que en vez de deslizar hacia abajo pueda paginar el formulario para que se vea mejor, he visto cómo se pagina pero la respuesta en ListView pero yo necesito es paginar el formulario en CreateView

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

No es posible paginar un formulario con Django. Django se usa para el backend, y lo que propones necesitaría de un frontend dinámico. Tendrías que hacerlo con Javascript, Ajax, etc. Pero no con Django.